# Unity get data from external app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna know how usually launchers applications handle the login information with client to send the information while loading the game (unity in this case) and they retrieve who's logged from the launcher information. Tried to figure out a couple times and i was thinking of write in a temporary file but i don't know what's the best practice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my way to handle this :

1) Launcher performs an authentification request on a webservice.
Send login / password and get back an identification token.

2) Launcher exit itself and start the game executable, giving the token as parameter. (C# process class)

3) The game is started and validate the token with the webservice.
(Exit if not valid)

4) When the client joins a server, it tells the webservice.
When the server receives the connection, it checks the webservice to be sure the user has the right to be here.

Comment: Thanks i was thinking of the same idea of getting the token but what you mean exactly by passing it to the game, via thread's? as a process parameter to the game?

Comment: As a process parameter, using Process.Start()

Comment: so i should use the recv of process in unity right? just some dumb questions but i'm not used much for process parsing

Comment: I'm using System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs (). It's better than recv to me because this kind of data only need to be parsed once.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy ;)